# Using scala.Singleton as a type constraint is inconsistent?

Tags: scala, types

I was running some examples using Singleton in scala and am stuck on something that seems inconsistent. Here's a minimal example:

```
trait X {
  type T <: Inner
  trait Inner {
    def innerMethod(config: T)
  }

  def outerMethod(config: T)
}
```

If I do

```
def add[U <: X](a: U#T, b: U#T) = {
  a.innerMethod(b)
}
```

It fails to compile, as expected, since `a` could be of type `obj1.T` and `b` could be of type `obj2.T` Constraining `U` to be `Singleton` solves the problem:

```
def add[U <: X with Singleton](a: U#T, b: U#T) = {
  a.innerMethod(b)
}
```

However, the following also fails to compile:

```
def add[U <: X with Singleton](a: U, b: U#T) = {
  a.outerMethod(b)
}
```

The error being:

> Error:(15, 21) type mismatch;
>
> found   : b.type (with underlying typeU#T)
>
> required: a.T

It seems that Singleton constraint would force `U` to be of type `a.type` and then `b` would be of type `a.T`.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you expect that T is object independent type, that is not: for each object of type X there is unique abstract T type.

For outerMethod,

```
def outerMethod(X#T) = ...
```

should be enough,
for innerMethod, the type of objects on which the function is called should be the same X#T.

Check it out

```
class Outer {
type T<: Inner
class Inner {
    def that(that:Outer#T) = that
}
def that(that:Outer#T) = that
}
class Outer2 extends Outer{
    type T = Inner
    val in = new T
}
object Obj {
    def add[U <: Outer](a: U#T, b: U#T) = {
        a.that(b)
    }
    def add[U<:Outer](a:U, b: U#T): Unit = {
        a.that(b)
    }
}
val out = new Outer2
Obj.add(out.in, out.in)
Obj.add(out, out.in)
```

Comment: I realize that T depends on the object, and that is what I want to enforce. You are simply weakening the type constraint on the method. For the inner method want the two arguments to be the same type. I.e there is an object x such that the first argument is x.T and the second is also x.T. I get that by add 'with Singleton'. What I can't express is for the outer method, there exists and object x, where the first argument is x.type, and the second is x.T.